# Why $\psi: \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z_n\times \mathbb Z_m$ is surjective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I denote $\mathbb Z_n:=\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$. In my lecture, we proved that $\mathbb Z/nm\mathbb Z\cong \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$ whenever $(m,n)=1$ are coprime. To do so, my teacher say that $\psi:\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z_n\times \mathbb Z_m$ defined by $$\psi(k)=([k]_n,[k]_m),$$ where $[k]_n:= k+n\mathbb Z$ denotes the class of $k$ in $\mathbb Z_n$.
I spent rather long time on this, but I don't see why this application is surjective. If $([s]_n,[t]_m)\in \mathbb Z_n\times \mathbb Z_m$ how can I find $k\in\mathbb Z$ s.t. $\psi(k)=([s]_n,[t]_m)$ ?

Comment: What you are asking is precisely the statement of Chinese Remainder Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), maybe your teacher assumed that you were familiar with it?

Answer (score 4):

The kernel of the group homomorphism $\psi$ is $m\mathbb{Z}\cap n\mathbb{Z}=mn\mathbb{Z}$, because $m$ and $n$ are coprime.

The homomorphism theorems provide the induced homomorphism $\bar{\psi}\colon\mathbb{Z}_{mn}\to\mathbb{Z}_m\times\mathbb{Z}_n$ which is injective and has the same image as $\psi$. Since domain and codomain of $\bar{\psi}$ have the same number of elements, the map $\bar{\psi}$ is also surjective; hence $\psi$ is surjective.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Since $(m,n)=1$ there are $u,v\in\mathbb Z$ s.t. $um+nv=1$. Then, take $$k=sum+tvn.$$

Comment: But $\psi(k)=([sum]_n,[tvn]_m)$. How do you get $([s]_n,[t]_m)$ ?

Comment: But $sum=s-svn$. Therefore $[sum]_n=[s]_n$.