Order of an element in relation to surjective homomorphism
Bear with me, I am a less the mediocre math student; I need help with this problem - and how to tackle those in general. I really am not comfortable about homomorphisms or isomorphisms.
Problem:
(i) Consider $G=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}.$ Does there exist a surjective grouphomomorphism $\Phi\colon\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow G?$
Start of solution:
I have a vague idea that it might have something to do with the order an element $g\in G.$ I figured that the highest order of an element from $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is $4$ and $6$ for $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$. So the least common multiple of $4$ and $6$ is $12$. Now i am stuck. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3879073/104041

You need Chinese reminder theorem to properly solve that.

Thank you. I didn't expect answers this soon, so i wont be able to look at the proposed hints any time in the next few hours. I hope that's fine. Sincerely

Duplicate of this + this and probably hundreds of others. $\ \ $

For any group $C$, a surjective homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to C$ exists if and only if $C$ is cyclic.
